# Excel - How to count cells with relative conditions

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I'm trying to use a count function that counts the number of cells in a column labelled "Success" if the relative cell in the same row (but different column) says a specific title, e.g. "Car services"

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, "Success", B:B, B2)
```

Comment: Works like a dream. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A21="success")*(B1:B21="car services"))
```

for this situation:

[image]